# Child class of a nested parent class can't access parent's protected member

Tags: c++

Code snippet below:

```
template<int M, int N>
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
        virtual void echo() { std::cout << _var << std::endl; }
    protected:
        char _var = 'b';
    };

    class C : public A<M, N>::B {
    public:
        C() { _var = 'c'; }
    };
};


int main()
{
    A<1, 1>::C cc; 
    cc.echo(); 
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2019 (v142) and C++ 14 Standard to compile, gets the following error:

[Visual Studio Compile Error: '_var' identifier not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlbU.png)

Can anyone help me solve or understand this issue? Much appreciated!

Comment: Please copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build-log into your question.

Comment: try `this->_var` instead.

Comment: To partially respond to your question as asked .....  In `C`s constructor, do `this->_var = 'c';`.     Look up "dependent expression" for an explanation of why that is (often) necessary when accessing a member of a templated base.    More generally (addressing a design concern you didn't ask about) it is often considered better for `C`'s constructor to call a constructor of `B` (in its initialiser list) and let `B` worry about initialising its own members.